# Loading and rendering the contents of the window before displaying alert

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm new to `Electron` (just like to English :).
I'm trying to output a simple `alert` after loading and rendering the contents of the main window.
**index.html:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
    Here's some content and images. A lot of them.
    ...
    <script src="alert.js"></script>
  </body>  
</html>
```

**alert.js:**

```
//Simple alert with some system information
alert("!@#$%^&*");
```

But an alert appears before the contents of the window are drawn. `Defer` and `async` don't help (i.e. `<script defer async src="alert.js"></script>`). What am I doing wrong? It seems to me that this is a very simple and stupid question, but I can not find an answer.
**UPD:**
The only way I found for now is to use `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function(){
     alert("!@#$%^&*");
}, 300);
```

Comment: I think script runs just after your body content is fetched and sent to parse, to run alert.js after content rendering, in jquery, you should try `$(window).on('load', function(){
    alert("sdfsd");
})`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript alert loads before page displays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280575/javascript-alert-loads-before-page-displays)

Comment: @Rahul Jain. I have not yet become acquainted with jquery. Where do I insert this code?

Comment: You don't need jQuery: `window.addEventListener("load",x=>alert("hello world"))
`

Comment: @HMR. This code shows alert defore rendering contents of the window too.

Comment: @Artik, yea, but could you tell me why this approach isn't working? It is intended to do this, no?

Comment: @Rahul Jain. I wish I knew! But I've tried all the options I have found! Only the version with setTimeout works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611713/running-javascript-after-page-is-fully-rendered

Comment: @Rahul Jain. It is about setTimeout too. I'm curious, is this the only way?

Comment: A more natural "electron-way" of doing it would be adding a `'dom-ready'` event listener to your browserwindow in **main** process and pop up custom alert window from there. No need to hack these things in renderer process at all costs

Comment: Also, `window.onload = () => { alert('resource has loaded') }` should work here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your code is at the bottom of the page you can us an IIFE (Immediately Invoking Function Expression):

```
(function() {
alert("!@#$%^&*");
}());
```

You can also use a setTimeout:

```
(function() {
    setTimeout(function () { 
        alert("!@#$%^&*"); 
    } , 2000)
}());
```

Comment: Just saw a similar solution:) I mean setTimeout. But isn't it a crutch?